# Centering Images and than fade in

Tags: jquery, css

Here is the combination of CSS and jQuery I use to center images, but I would like to hide images before they are centered, and than to "fadeIn" those somehow.

CSS:

```
.image_block {
       position:relative;
       height:200px;
       width:200px;
 }

.img_block img {
    position: absolute;
    top:50%;
    left:50%;
    display:block;      
 }
```

jQuery:

```
$('.img_block').find('img').each(function() {
  $(this).css({     
  'margin-left':  - $(this).outerWidth()/2,
  'margin-top':  - $(this).outerHeight()/2
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You could hide your images in the CSS with:

```
.img_block img { opacity: 0; }
```

And then include an opacity animation on the image in question with jQuery .animate():

```
$('.img_block').find('img').each(function() {
  $(this).css({     
    'margin-left':  - $(this).outerWidth()/2,
    'margin-top':  - $(this).outerHeight()/2
  });
  $(this).animate({     
    'opacity': 1
  });
});
```

Comment: +1 Good answer. Just out of curiosity, why `.animate()` and not `.fadeIn()` ?

Comment: Thanks @DrydenLong. .fadeIn() essentially achieves the same result, that is, animating the opacity. I think the OP would be fine to save some typing and use $(this).fadeIn(); if so inclined. Great point.

Comment: Yeah, I was curious what the difference was between the two so I searched and it looks like `.fadeIn()` essentially uses `.animate()` so there isn't much difference. It seems like `.animate()` provides a little more granular control over the animation though.

Comment: Animating the opacity wouldn't show the div since it's `display: none`. Need to end up at `display: block`, which is what `.fadeIn()` does.

Comment: It really doesn't matter which effect will be used as long as images are not visible during the jQuery centering

Answer (score 0):

First hide your images using `css`:

```
.img_block img {
  position: absolute;
  top:50%;
  left:50%;
  // hide images
  display:none;      
}
```

Then in your jQuery, show them:

```
$('.img_block').find('img').each(function() {
  $(this).css({     
    'margin-left':  - $(this).outerWidth()/2,
    'margin-top':  - $(this).outerHeight()/2
  });
  // EDIT:
  $(this).show('slow');
  // OR
  $(this).fadeIn();
  // OR
  $(this).slideToggle('slow');
  // OR....
  setTimeout(function() {
    // show it here.
    $(this).show('slow');
  }, 1000);
});
```

Comment: It's basically the same thing, I still see some image jumping, maybe some callback function would do the trick? or better to say - images should not be visible before centering, after that they can fade-in or whatever.

Comment: almost there, strange thing that sometimes images fade nicely, and sometimes jumping appears, especially in chrome

Comment: Here is working fine, please check this JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/leonardorb/upSh4/

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all, I managed to make this work on my way:

here is the solution

CSS:

```
.img_block img {
  position: absolute;
  top:50%;
  left:50%;
  display:block;
  opacity:0;
  background-color: transparent;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 200ms linear;
  -moz-transition: opacity 200ms linear;
  -ms-transition: opacity 200ms linear;
  -o-transition: opacity 200ms linear;
  transition: opacity 200ms linear;         
}
```

jQuery:

```
//center images 
function centerImages() {               
$('.img_block').find('img').each(function() {
  $(this).css({     
  'margin-left':  - $(this).outerWidth()/2,
  'margin-top':  - $(this).outerHeight()/2
  });
 });
}
//fadein images
function fadeImages(){
  $('.img_block').find('img').each(function() {
    $(this).delay(500).animate({'opacity': 1}, 0);
   });
  }
$.when(centerImages()).done(fadeImages);
```